# How to store the data from edittext to android sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext

I am a new developer on Android and I want store user data in database using sqlite. For that design .xml file username as edittext and take button, after fill all text fields when click the button all the data is stored in database. and show this data on screen.....

Comment: What have you tried? it seems that you didn't try anything because this is a really simple thing.you could have achieved by using just the sample program on http://developer.android.com/index.html

Comment: You can find examples simply by google, read basics of sqlite first and post code what you have tried . Sqlite e.g link http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are useful tutorial and will help you

http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/

http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/1/

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html